# update MYSQL, download file and redirect

Tags: php, mysql

i have been looking into this all day and stuck. I have a basic PHP script which updates a table. with details passed to it and then downloads the file from the upload directory.

```
$user = isset($_GET['use'])? $_GET['use'] : null;
$route = isset($_GET['rou'])? $_GET['rou'] : null;
$expires = isset($_GET['exp'])? $_GET['exp'] : null;
$itemnu = isset($_GET['item'])? $_GET['item'] : null;
$host="host";   
$username="username";
$password="password"; 
$db_name="username";  
$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("can not select DB"); 
$query = "INSERT INTO database.table(item,name,expiry) VALUES ('$itemnu', '$user',   '$expires')";  
mysql_query($query) or die('Query "' . $query . '" failed: ' . mysql_error());  
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Refresh\" content=\"0; url=/upload/" . $route . "\">";
```

What i need to do now is redirect back to homepage. However you i understand you can't redirect after a download with PHP, and if i redirect before it doesn't work. i have tried

> fopen and file_get_contents

but as the files will be a varity of microsoft, text and pdf i couldn't get it to work. i also tried (removed as part of edit
I have looked a javascript and can't work how to download a file using a php Variable. Any help appricated, thanks in advance. There is no requirment for a php script, it can be anything that works. 
This is the upload file

```
<?php
$target = "../upload/";
$target = $target . str_replace(" ","_",( $_FILES['file']['name']));
$current = time();
$name=addslashes($_POST['title']);
$owner=$_POST['owner'];
$pic=str_replace(" ","_",($_FILES['file']['name']));
$time = strtotime($_POST['timestamp']);
$grade= implode(',&#32;', $_POST['g_group']);
$Loc= implode(',&#32;', $_POST['l_group']);
        mysql_connect("host", "database", "password") or die(mysql_error()) ;
        mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()) ;
        $query =("INSERT INTO UPLOAD (title,owner,faoGrade, foaLocation,date, expiry,route)
        VALUES
        ('$name', '$owner','$grade','$Loc','$current','$time', '$pic')");
        mysql_query($query);

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target))
                            {
        echo  "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
                    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file using " . query ;
                                    }
?>
```

and the download amended

```
<?php  
$user = isset($_GET['use'])? $_GET['use'] : null;
$route = isset($_GET['rou'])? $_GET['rou'] : null;
$expires = isset($_GET['exp'])? $_GET['exp'] : null;
$itemnu = isset($_GET['item'])? $_GET['item'] : null;
$host="host";   
$username="username";
$password="password"; 
$db_name="database";  
$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("can not select DB"); 
$query = "INSERT INTO database.READ(item,name,expiry) VALUES ('$itemnu', '$user',     '$expires')";  
mysql_query($query) or die('Query "' . $query . '" failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
sleep(20);                                                   //added didn't help
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');                 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$route);                  
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");    
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($route));                 //added didn't work
readfile('/upload/'.$route);
header("refresh: 150; roster.php?action=Home"); 
exit; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't really be done 'server side'.

But as the browser usually keeps the same 'webpage' open while the download progresses, that page, can after the download has began redirect wherever you want. (ie using Javascript)

So its the page that contains the link to the download script you need to modify, not the actual download script itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the content-type to application/pdf

I have just finished creating something similar to this in PHP for work, I had to create a file uploader, when a user uploads a pdf file to the webpage it will run a shell exec command on that file to decrypt it and allow more permissions and then it will automatically be re downloaded to the users computer, I also know that you are missing some code to help this along. Also, your PHP way of doing it you're always going to be reading the file 'upload.pdf' what if the file has a different name?

```
readfile($fileName . '.pdf');
```

and lastly, on the line just before exit; you have an extra semi-colon

Comment: sorry this was a copy of the file before i changed it. It did have the $route instead of upload.pdf. the semi colon??? removed.  Still downloaded file won't open with a converter???

Comment: I see, well from what I can tell it's because it isn't waiting for the file to finished the processing, it's downloading it straight away and missing some of the content or something of the stuff behind the file which is causing it to be a lower file size than what it should be, try putting a sleep on it... so it loads for 10 seconds after upload then carries on with the script

Comment: Daniel, Spot on, just done a test and the file was 2kb, The size on server is 36kb. At least i know why just need to find a fix.

Comment: just before you send the headers try putting this line: sleep(10);

this will make it load for 10 seconds before carrying on with the script, if it still comes back with a low file size then it's because of the file upload script reducing it, if it comes back fine then it's because it's trying to process everything too fast

Comment: Had already tried sleep(20); still 2KB, loking through the code now.Looking into other ideas.

Comment: Okay then, well can I see your upload script?

Comment: mysql_query($query) or die('Query "' . $query . '" failed: ' .     mysql_error()); 
    sleep(20);
    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');                 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$route);                  
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-    check=0");                     
    readfile('/upload/'.$route);
    header("refresh: 150; roster.php?action=Home"); 
    exit;

Comment: That's the download... surely there should be an upload too?

Comment: the upload is a seprate page. i will post both shortly

Comment: Okai dokie, I know it's a problem with the Uploader because it happened to me once

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and see what happens

```
$query = "INSERT INTO database.table(item,name,expiry) VALUES ('$itemnu','$user','$expires')";  

if(mysql_query($query))
{
    header('Location:homepage.html');
}else{
   print_r($_GET); //check GET requests
   die; 
}
```